# Invalid grant error when do AuthenticationClient.UsernamePasswordAsync()

Tags: .net, aws

I have a simple console .NET application with the next lines:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(consumerKey, consumerSecret, username, (password + secuToken), sfURL);
```

When I run it on the old machine which connects to SalesForce successfully for years, it works fine. If I clone this machine and run the same application then I get the error:

```
ForceAuthException: InvalidGrant
at Salesforce.Common.AuthenticationClient.<UsernamePasswordAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
```

Did I miss some setup steps?

**Notes**:

1. The old machine is actually in one AWS account and the new machine is cloned and moved to another AWS account.
2. This simple application doesn't work also on my local machine. But it works fine on many machines in the old AWS account.
3. I tried on several SalesForce .NET packages (Ex. 1.3.2 and 2.1.0)
4. WireShark shows me that the client and server do some interactions: Handshake and then sending Application Data:
   [image: WireShark Logs (IPs are hidden)]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior was the range of [trusted IP addresses](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=security_networkaccess.htm&type=5&language=en_US). Adding the IP addresses of the new machines solved the problem.